# Using fancyhdr for small-caps headers with book documentclass

Tags: header-footer, double-sided, single-sided

I am having some problems with using the package `fancyhdr`. My goal is to have small-caps headers (instead of the default upper-case) with the book class and I would like, if possible, to write a code which works regardless if I use the option `twoside` or oneside.

There is attached a simplified preamble; *firstpage* is a single-page pdf used as front. The chapters are tex files *cap1*, *cap2*, etc, while *mybib* is for the bibliography.

If I simply use the command `\pagestyle{fancy}`, a weird thing happens: the headers disappear and a decorative line appears. I tried several other commands but nothing worked.

```
\documentclass[12pt, openright, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%Abstract
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\fncyblank}{\fancyhf{}}
\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\cleardoublepage\fncyblank\null \vfill\begin{center}%
\bfseries \LARGE \abstractname \end{center}}%
{\vfill\null}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\includepdf{firstpage}


\selectlanguage{english}%
\begin{abstract}
Test.
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\include{caps/cap1}
\include{caps/cap2}

\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following example will help, but I am not sure if it is the desired result.

```
\documentclass[12pt,
%  oneside
]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,
  headheight=15.5pt% <- as suggested by fancyhdr
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% <- remove headrule

%Abstract
\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{empty}% <- changed to "empty"
  \null\vfill
  \begin{center}\bfseries \LARGE \abstractname \end{center}%
}%
{\vfill\null\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
First page
\begin{abstract}
Test.
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Or with the additional information from comments below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,
  headheight=15.5pt% <- as suggested by fancyhdr
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\scshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\scshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% <- remove headrule

%Abstract
\newenvironment{abstract}%
{\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{plain}% <- changed to "plain"
  \null\vfill
  \begin{center}\bfseries \LARGE \abstractname \end{center}%
}%
{\vfill\null\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman}
First page
\begin{abstract}
Test.
\end{abstract}
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, the end result is not the desired one but at least it's a start. The decorative headrule is no-problem. The headings should be in the left/right position exactly as in a twoside, openright book. Default footnotes should be left as they are.

Comment: Do not worry about the case of a oneside book. For now, I'm interested only in getting it right for a twoside, openright book.

Comment: Another thing: the page with abstract needs to have the page number in it (roman, since it is frontmatter). In your example, it does not, but I believe that the origin of the weird phenomenon is from exactly the fancyhf command used there.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I noticed that headheight=15.5pt looks better (less wasted space) than the default option. Seems weird, I thought LaTeX defaults were pretty good, typographically speaking.